# MySQL: Location of data when developing on different machines

Tags: mysql

Having just installed MySQL, which I want to use for research software development, I face the question where should I store my data files?

I have three computers (home, work, laptop), all of which have a development environment (Java/Eclipse) and I want all those machines to be able to access the database(s).

If I just had one machine, it would be a no brainer and I would just use localhost.

I can't decide where best to locate the data files. The options I am considering (but happy to hear other views) are:

1) Just store on the local machine and let Dropbox take care of syncing the data.
The data might get quite large and exceed the storage capacity on at least one of the machines and it might also take a long time to sync?

2) Use a Network Storage device (I have a Synology unit)

3) I have my own domain registered so I could use that?

4) Use a cloud based service.
Not sure how these work, the costs and the backup options.

In all the above, unless I use localhost, I am concerned about access times if I have to go "over the internet", especially if I make heavy use of SQL queries/updates.

I am also worried about backip up the databases in case I need to restore.

You might ask why I want to use mySQL? In the future, I might want to do a PHP roll out and MySQL seems the way to go.

Thans in advance.

G

Answer (score 0):

maybe consider local installs on each machine, but with mysql replication. that way, if your laptop doesnt have internet service, you can still work with the local data, even though it might be a tiny bit out of date.

Replication also kinda addresses backups.

Comment: TY. I would need to look at what this actuallu means, but this sounds like a good solution. I'm guessing that MySQL has some form of replication/syncing; which would be great!

Comment: @Graham yes, that's correct. It's had the feature for a very long time, so there should be plenty of info on the net on how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure size of your application. If it's huge, you could use an independent DATABASE server, otherwise use one of your computers as place to store data (use the one with biggest disk and memory size).

I think you wonder how to visit data in a different computer, actually no need to worry about that, because it always use database connector with IP/port defined in your application. If you use Java/Eclipse, you should use JDBC to visit database.

For example, JDBC setting looks like below.

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myuser", "root", "root"); // please replace localhost and 3306 with IP and port of your database
String sql = "select * from yourtable"; // your query
Statement st = (Statement)conn.createStatement();
st.executeQuery(sql);
```

Comment: Very useful. Thanks. I have a lot to learn but this gives me a great start.

Comment: One issue is that the database is likely to be om a home computer, with no fixed IP addrress. I think there are ways of allocating a static IP - but I need to get into the router to do that. BUt that is outside the scope of this discussion.

Comment: sure, maybe some methods that I am not sure, but at least it's no difficult to visit DB in another computer if you have interface.